# Standards slip?

Tags: meaning-in-context, collocations

Please explain the meaning of the words in bold

> people feel educational **standards slipped** when the goverment cut finances.

It's one of collocations I've learned but I can't see it in some dictionaries as well as guess its meaning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions of **slip** include:

- "go into a worse state, often because a lack of control or care" ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slip))
- "pass or change to a lower, worse, or different condition, typically in a gradual or imperceptible way" ([Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slip))

So:

> people feel educational standards **slipped** when the goverment cut finances.

means

> people feel [that] educational standards **worsened** [*or* **fell**] when the goverment cut finances.